# Python regex negation within regex

Tags: python, regex

Given:

```
ABC
content 1
123
content 2
ABC
content 3
XYZ
```

Is it possible to create a regex that matches the shortest version of "ABC[\W\w]+?XYZ"

Essentially, I'm looking for "ABC followed by any characters terminating with XYZ, but don't match if I encounter ABC in between" (but think of ABC as a potential regex itself, as it would not always be a set length...so ABC or ABcC could also match)

So, more generally: REGEX1 followed by any character and terminated by REGEX2, not matching if REGEX1 occurs in between.

In this example, I would not want the first 4 lines.

(I'm sure this explanation could potentially need...further explanation haha)

**EDIT:**

Alright, I see the need for further explanation now! Thanks for the suggestions thus far. I'll at least give you all more to think about while I start looking into how each of your proposed solutions can be applied to my problem.

**Proposal 1:** Reverse the string contents and the regex.

This is certainly a very fun hack that solves the problem based on what I explained. In simplifying the issue, I failed to also mention that the same thing could happen in reverse because the ending signature could exist later on also (and has proven to be in my specific situation). That introduces the problem illustrated below:

```
ABC
content 1
123
content 2
ABC
content 3
XYZ
content 4
MNO
content 5
XYZ
```

In this instance, I would check for something like "ABC through XYZ" meaning to catch [ABC, content 1, XYZ]...but accidentally catching [ABC, content 1, 123, content 2, ABC, content 3, XYZ]. Reversing that would catch [ABC, content 3, XYZ, content 4, MNO, content 5, XYZ] instead of the [ABC, content 2, XYZ] that we want again. The point is to try to make it as generalized as possible because I will also be searching for things that could potentially have the same starting signature (regex "ABC" in this case), and different ending signatures.

If there is a way to build the regexes so that they encapsulate this sort of limitation, it could prove much easier to just reference that any time I build a regex to search for in this type of string, rather than creating a custom search algorithm that deals with it.

**Proposal 2:** A+B+C+[^A]+[^B]+[^C]+XYZ with IGNORECASE flag

This seems nice in the case that ABC is finite. Think of it as a regex in itself though. For example:

```
Hello!GoodBye!Hello.Later.
```

VERY simplified version of what I'm trying to do. I would want "Hello.Later." given the start regex Hello[!.] and the end Later[!.]. Running something simply like Hello[!.]Later[!.] would grab the entire string, but I'm looking to say that if the start regex Hello[!.] exists between the first starting regex instance found and the first ending regex instance found, ignore it.

The convo below this proposal indicates that I might be limited by regular language limitations similar to the parentheses matching problem (Google it, it's fun to think about). The purpose of this post is to see if I do in fact have to resort to creating an underlying algorithm that handles the issue I'm encountering. I would very much like to avoid it if possible (in the simple example that I gave you above, it's pretty easy to design a finite state machine for...I hope that holds as it grows slightly more complex).

**Proposal 3:** ABC(?:(?!ABC).)*?XYZ with DOTALL flag

I like the idea of this if it actually allows ABC to be a regex. I'll have to explore this when I get in to the office tomorrow. Nothing looks too out of the ordinary at first glance, but I'm entirely new to python regex (and new to actually applying regexes in code instead of just in theory homework)

Comment: Would it be easier to just reverse the line and look for `ZYX.+?CBA` or something?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty `.+?` Why not `.*`?

Comment: @arxanas I'd assume that you're correct, I just copied the op's choice of `.+?`.  Good catch though.

Comment: Searching backwards seems like a good solution.

Comment: Alaheu, please, see the discussion below my answer to make the point of the question more clear.

Comment: Alright, sorry about the delay. I'm working on a big EDIT to my post that incorporates all of the responses so far. Should be finished shortly! Nolen, this suggestion will appear as "Proposal 1" in the edit.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer according to your edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regex solution would be `ABC(?:(?!ABC).)*?XYZ` with the `DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Definitely my favorite solution.  If the data can be large, reversing the data could be expensive; and this is a straightforward way to express the desired constraints within a single regular expression.

Comment: It doesn't work if we _think of ABC as a potential regex itself_, though, at least _as is_.

Comment: I like this a lot more.  Reversing is a bit of a hack, even if it works.

Comment: I do want to mention one thing that I didn't in my recent post update. This would need to take [\W\w]* instead of .* into account because the string is spread across multiple lines. Would that be as simple as ABC(?:(?!ABC)[\W\w])*?XYZ
I'll check this stuff out in the morning! Thanks for the input thus far.

Comment: @alaheu, just to point out that [\W\w] is quite _paradoxal_: it would means "the class of all characters which are not a word-char and which are a word-char" :o)

Comment: .* doesn't catch newline characters. This [\W\w] would include all whitespace and non-whitespace which is what I need :D (if you know a better solution, would gladly hear it!)

Comment: @alaheu: By default, `.` doesn't match a newline character, but with the `DOTALL` flag it matches _any_ character.

Comment: Yeah, both work the same for my purpose. ([\W\w] without DOTALL flag...or . with DOTALL flag)

Comment: Ok. Hum seems I definitely don't get what you needed anyway :o)

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

So after reading your further explanations, I would say that my previous proposal, as well as MRAB's one are somehow similar and won't be of any help here. Your problem *is* actually the prolem of *nested structures*.

Think of your 'prefix' and 'suffix' as symbols. You could easily replace them with an opening and a closing parenthesis or whatever, and what you want is being able to match only the smallest (then deepest) pair ...

For example if your prefix is 'ABC.' and your suffix is 'XYZ.':

```
ABChello worldABCfooABCbarXYZ
```

You want to get only `ABCbarXYZ`.

It's the same if the prefix is `(`, and the suffix is `)`, the string:

```
(hello world(foo(bar)
```

It would match ideally only `(bar)` ...

Definitely you have to use a [context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) (like programming languages do: [C grammar](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html), [Python grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html)) and a [parser](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2008s/clt231/nltk-0.9.5/doc/en/ch07.html), or make your own by using regex as well as the iterating and storing mechanisms of your programming language.

But that's not possible with only regular expressions. They would probably help in your algorithm, but they just are not designed to handle that alone. Not the good tool for that job ... You cannot inflate tires with a screwdriver. Therefore, you will have to use some external mechanisms, not complicated though, to store the context, your position in the nested stack. Using your regular expression in each single context still may be possible.

*Finite state machines* are *finite*, and nested structures have an *arbitrary depth* that would require your automaton to grow arbitrarily, thus they are not [*regular languages*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

> Since recursion in a grammar allows the definition of nested syntactic structures, any language (including any programming language) which allows nested structures is a context-free language, not a regular language. For example, the set of strings consisting of balanced parentheses [like a LISP program with the alphanumerics removed] is a context-free language
>   [see here](http://www.augustana.ca/~jmohr/courses/common/csc370/lecture_notes/chomsky.html)

### Former proposal (not relevant anymore)

If I do:

```
>>> s = """ABC
content 1
123
content 2
ABC
content 3
XYZ"""
>>> r = re.compile(r'A+B+C+[^A]+[^B]+[^C]+XYZ', re.I)
>>> re.findall(r,s)
```

I get

```
['ABC\ncontent 3\nXYZ']
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: The solution is not extensible, though.

Comment: Not extensible? hmmm in what sense? A regex by definition is not extensible,since it's regular and finite.

Comment: Read the OP's question. The general case of this is that he wants to match a string that is prefix and suffix by 2 regex, but there is no prefix regex is between the matched string.

Comment: And so ? It works. I don't understand your problem (what you said is exactly what I'm doing here).

Comment: Tell me how you would extend your solution to the case prefix = regex "ABC" and suffix = regex "XYZ" (currently, your prefix is regex "A+B+C+" and it will match cases like `AABBCCKKLJLXYZ`). An extensible solution is one that when you substitute another regex in, it would work.

Comment: That what is asked by OP. Read again the question. He said _but think of ABC as a potential regex itself, as it would not always be a set length...so ABC or ABcC could also match_. That is. If you want a strict "ABC", just remove the pluses. There is no such thing "extensibility" with a regular language. It's case by case. And this one is working, so far. It matches, may you like it or not :-)

Comment: I don't think there is any point furthering this discussion since we can't come to term on our points of view.

Comment: What the OP doesn't want to match are things like ABCABCXYZ, or ABCXYUIEABCIEURYXYZ. Now, I think I understood what you meant. If what he wants is a kind of a _variable_ in a regex, like if the prefix is "AaBBBCcC", so the forbidden string in the between would be exactly the same "AaBBBCcC", then it's just not possible with standard regex since, as FSA, there is no stack. It's still possible by using some external mechanisms from the programming language, but not with only "standard" regex.

Comment: (that exactly the same problem as matching nested parenthesis or braces which regex, which is not possible)

Comment: Yeah, that's my point. I'm not sure if the forbidden string has to be exactly the same, or the forbidden string can be any string that matches the prefix regex.

Comment: Ok I see now. So if the forbidden string has to be exactly the same, there is just no solution with only regex, because by design there is no memorization (see _finite state machines_). It's though possible to build dynamically an expression with the prog language depending on the input, but I think that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Alright, so I get the general direction of where you mini conversation is going here. Sorry for jumping back on so late. I'm making a larger response EDIT to my original post that deals with this also. It will appear as Proposal 2.

Comment: It didn't seem like this would require any kind of memorization, but I'm fresh out of school so I haven't had much practice in recognizing/building regexes yet outside of theoretical homework. Just getting used to the application process.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method of solving this problem: not trying to do it in one regex. You could split the string by the first regex, and then use the second one on the last part.

Code is the best explanation:

```
s = """ABC
content 1
123
content 2
ABC
content 3
XYZ
content 4
XYZ"""

# capturing groups to preserve the matched section
prefix = re.compile('(ABC)')
suffix = re.compile('(XYZ)')

# prefix.split(s) == ['', 'ABC', [..], 'ABC', '\ncontent 3\nXYZ\ncontent 4\nXYZ']
#                          prefixmatch ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ rest ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
prefixmatch, rest = prefix.split(s)[-2:]

# suffix.split(rest,1) == ['\ncontent 3\n', 'XYZ', '\ncontent 4\nXYZ']
#                          ^^ interior ^^   ^^^^^ suffixmatch
interior, suffixmatch = suffix.split(rest,1)[:2]

# join the parts up.
result = '%s%s%s' % (prefixmatch, interior, suffixmatch)

# result == 'ABC\ncontent 3\nXYZ'
```

Some points:

- there should be appropriate error handling (even just `try: ... except ValueError: ..` around the whole thing) to handle the case when either regex doesn't match at all and so the list unpacking fails.
- this assumes that the desired segment will occur immediately after the last occurrence of `prefix`, if not, then you can iterate through the results of `prefix.split(s)` two at a time (starting at index 1) and do the same splitting trick with `suffix` to find all the matches.
- this likely to be reasonably inefficient, since it creates quite a few intermediate data structures.